# How to slide to a specific slide on slider

Tags: jquery, html

I want to slide the slider to a specific slide using a url.  I am able to slide to a specific slide using the slide number but I need to slide to it using its id.

eg: If I open `slider.html?pic=sunset` it will slide the slider to the slide with `id=slide`

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: true,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
    });

    $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel",
        start: function (slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the index of the slide which has the id as 'sunset'..

If your flexslider HTML structure is like ..

```
<div id="slider">
     <div>...<img/>...</div>
     <div>...<img/>...</div>
     <div id="sunset">...<img/>...</div>
     <div>...<img/>...</div>
</div>
```

Try this code..

```
var index = $('#sunset').index();   // will give you 2
$('#slider').flexslider(index);   // will take you to that slide
```

Answer (score 4):

You can acces the slider object like:

```
var exampleSlider = $('#slider').data('flexslider');
// now you can access all the methods for example flexAnimate
exampleSlider.flexAnimate(..);
```

And for going to slide with index. You will need:

```
exampleSlider.flexslider(3);//3 is index here
```

Comment: Thanks..i tried it to implement it...but not able to do that..if you help me with this i will be very helpfull to you.

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: i tried to implement you code..but am not sure how to make it work with mine..logic i think we need:adding class to the slide where id is.

Comment: See for going to slide number 4, You can use `exampleSlider.flexslider(3)`. I am not sure how is it done based on image selector

Comment: but what i need is to slide to speicific slide using id :(

Comment: sorry.Not sure how could we do that :(